# Dual Boot Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 Stuck at Grub at Boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive, grub-efi

I have a problem with double booting Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04

I have 18.04 installed on my SSD in to the laptop. Recently I found my old HDD and thought give it a try and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it via a caddy.

So now I have a 'external' HDD that has Ubuntu 20.04 & I have a `internal` SSD that has Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

When external HDD is connected at boot the GRUB window appears and when I type `exit` it just continues to login screen with Ubuntu 20.04 which is installed on `external HDD` but when I plug out the external HDD the grub screen at the boot gives me error stating `image file is wrong` and it never boots up the 18.04

How can I solve this issue ? I want to remove 20.04 completely from my login

Answer (score 0):

Ah the wonderful logic of Grub, that "feature" is one I despise the most. The if not everything present in the configuration it will not boot, even when it has nothing to do with the boot chosen. Boot with the Ubuntu 20.04 present using the 18.04 as the drive to boot. Once in the 18.04 unmount the 20.04 drive and disconnect it. Then it is a simple re-install for a newly created config file. The procedure below for a simple straight forward install. Then another page with many complicated examples of the grub command for Ubuntu.

https://itsfoss.com/update-grub/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing